# Reference for functors in Kadeishvili's C_\infty paper

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, a-infinity-algebras, rational-homotopy-theory, reference-request

In his paper [Cohomology $C_\infty$-algebra and rational homotopy type](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1655v1), Tornike Kadeishvili describes how the rational cohomology of a simply-connected space carries the structure of a $C_\infty$-algebra, and how this structure determines the rational homotopy type of the space. (The result has been mentioned before on MathOverflow, eg in [these](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50238/poincare-duality-and-the-a-infty-structure-on-cohomology/50255#50255) [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36444/definition-of-an-e-infinity-algebra/36478#36478).)

I'm trying to follow the proofs, which are somewhat light on details. In particular, they rely on an adjoint pair of functors
$$\Gamma\colon CDGAlg \rightleftarrows DGLieCoalg \colon \mathcal{A}$$ introduced in section 4.3, between the categories of commutative differential graded algebras, and differential graded Lie coalgebras. The functor $\Gamma$ is given as the composition $$\Gamma\colon CDGAlg\stackrel{B}{\to}DGBialg\stackrel{Q}{\to}DGLieCoalg$$ where $B$ is a bar construction and $Q$ is the functor of indecomposables. The adjoint functor $\mathcal{A}$ is dual to the Chevalley-Eilenberg functor. There is a standard weak equivalence $\mathcal{A}\Gamma(A)\to A$.

I am struggling to find any reference to these functors in the papers cited in the bibliography. For the proof of Theorem 9.1 we seem to need that the functor $\mathcal{A}\Gamma$ applied to the weak equivalences of $C_\infty$-algebras $$\lbrace f_i\rbrace\colon (H(A),\lbrace m_i\rbrace )\to (A,\lbrace d, \mu, 0,\ldots\rbrace)$$ yields a weak equivalence $\mathcal{A}\Gamma(H(A))\to\mathcal{A}\Gamma(A)$ in $CDGAlg$, but this is not stated anywhere and is not obvious to me.

> Is the above true, and can anyone explain why?
>
> Where can I read more about the functors $\Gamma$ and $\mathcal{A}$ and their properties, in particular in the setting of $C_\infty$-algebras?

Comment: This is standard Koszul duality. Take your favourite book on rational homotopy theory.

Comment: Dear Fernando, please could you expand on your comment a little? I have two favourite books on RHT, and neither of them have Koszul duality in the index.

Comment: See for instance IV.22 in 

MR1802847 (2002d:55014) Félix, Yves; Halperin, Stephen; Thomas, Jean-Claude Rational homotopy theory. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 205. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2001. xxxiv+535 pp. ISBN: 0-387-95068-0 (Reviewer: John F. Oprea), 55P62 (18Gxx 55U35)

Comment: @Fernando: Thanks. Do you mean that the functors in that chapter are be (linearly) dual to the ones described above? What is still worrying me is that the weak equivalence $H(A)\to A$ is not a CDGA map, in particular it is only multiplicative up to boundaries. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all the arguments in Chapter 11 of the book downloadable at http://math.unice.fr/~brunov/Operads.html. This chapter deals with the bar and the cobar constructions for algebras over a Koszul operad. The last section [11.4] treats the extension to homotopy algebras.

The theorem "the bar-cobar construction for $C_\infty$-algebras sends $\infty$-quasi-isomorphisms to quasi-isomorphisms" is exactly Proposition 11.4.11 apply to the operad $P=Com$.

[Needless to say that this reference does not provide the very first proof of this fact for $C_\infty$-algebras. Let's just say that it is freely available on the net, so easily accessible.]

Comment: Thanks Bruno. This certainly seems to be the right general framework to prove this, and a lot more besides! I've begun reading.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any further question. I imagine that you were looking for a more ad hoc reference. Read this one with $P=Com$ and $P^{anti !}=Lie^*$ in mind. 

Answer (score 5):

Ben Walter and I make the functors $\Gamma$ and $A$ more explicit, by using an explicit model for the cofree Lie Coalgebra functor, in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610437).  We do not discuss the application to $\infty$-algebras as Bruno does in much greater generality. (We were interested in using explicit models to be able to compute, in particular in the long exact sequence of a fibration as we do in a sequel to this paper on Hopf invariants.)

Comment: Thanks Dev. The paper looks interesting, I'll take a look.